# Offline HTML5 iPad: Gmail and Docs

Tags: ipad, gmail, network

There was some recent news about the release of an HTML5-powered offline Gmail and Docs.  But it looks like these won't work on the iPad. Is this true? If so, is there a way that I can use these tools on my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari can handle HTML5.

What makes you think they won't work anyway?